How to click to list items through Puppeteer node js
I am trying to log in to my university's LMS through Puppeteer to scrape data. When I enter the dashboard, I try to click on the list item button, but it does not work. Here are the 12 list items' HTML code. I want to click on the 5th item [text: "View my current enrollments."]
When I try to click on the button by targeting span, 'a' tag, or link, it tells me that the selector does not exist or is undefined, even though I double-checked the selector and it exists. I also tried moving the mouse but I need the selector to create X and Y coordinates. Is there any other possible way to do it?
<ul class="row yic">

    <li class="col-md-3">
         <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/users/activeEnrollment_datesheet" target="_blank"><i      class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
         <span>View My Roll No Slip</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-md-3">
          <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/examination/my_surveys"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> 
         <span>View My Survey</span>
        <img style="display: block;position: absolute;width: 58px;right: 6px;top: 6px;" src="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/assets/images/new_icon.gif">
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/users/transcript"><i class="fa  fa-address-book"></i>  <span>View My Transcript</span>
    </a>
    </li>


        <li class="col-md-3">                                                                                        <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/users/planofstudy"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> 
<span>View My Plan of Study</span>                                                          </a>                                                                                                    </li>
                
        <li class="col-md-3">
         <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/users/activeEnrollment"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>View My Current Enrollments</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/finance/challan"><i class="fa fa-money"></i>
         <span> Semester Fee Voucher</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-md-3">
           <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/users/hostelportal"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>
        <span>My Hostel</span>
         </a>                                                                                               </li>

         <li class="col-md-3">
            <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/studentcourses/course_registration"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> 
            <span>Course Registration</span>
            </a>
          </li>

         <li class="col-md-3">
            <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/users/student_clearance"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <span>My Clearance</span>
            </a>
         </li>
                            

        <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/users/medical_profile"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i> <span>Medical Profile</span>
    </a>
    </li>

        <li class="col-md-3">
    <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/users/issue_listing/cosc241103020"><i class="fa fa-podcast"></i>
<span>Create Token(SFSC)</span>
    </a>
        </li>

    <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="https://my.kfueit.edu.pk/finance/download_facilitation_challan"><i class="fa fa-money"></i>
<span>Generate Challan</span>   
    </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

I tried every possible method, like targeting class, 'a' tag, link, span, and page. evaluate but all of these fail. My latest puppeteer code looks like this.
"
(async()=>{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://my.kfueit.edu.pk');

  await page.type('#username', 'COSC241103020');
  await page.type('#password', 'kfu#1122');

  const captchaElement = await page.$('#captImg img');
  const screenshotPath = 'captcha.png';
  await captchaElement.screenshot({ path: screenshotPath });

  const captchaText = await solveCaptchaWithOCR(screenshotPath);
  console.log('--captchatext----',captchaText)

  const answer = parseMathProblem(captchaText);
  console.log('=====answer====', answer);

  if (answer !== null) {
    await page.type('.form-control', answer.toString());
  } else {
    console.error('Could not solve the captcha');
  }

  console.log('------set----')

  await page.click('#submit');
  await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    console.log("Found elements:", document.querySelectorAll("li.col-md-3").length);
  });
})();

"

You have a race condition in your .click()/.waitForNavigation(). Remove the awaits there and wrap in a Promise.all(). Beyond that, it's hard to help since I can't see the site. Your selector would work fine if the HTML shown here were all that there was on the page, but there must be other issues causing problems. Are you sure the elements aren't in an iframe or shadow root, for starters?

@ggorlen Here is the link to the site'my.kfueit.edu.pk', and the login details are:
username: COSC241103020
password: kfu#1122

Thanks, the data is indeed inside an iframe, so you'll need to query that frame and then dip into the contents. What data are you trying to get, or action you're ultimately trying to take on the page?

@ggorlen I want to click on a button whose text is("View my current Enrollments")

Thanks, I'd try Trying to click a button within an iframe with puppeteer
